# Extracting table from a website using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, web, screen-scraping

Hi I wanted to extract a table from the url = 'http://www.nativeplant.com/plants/search/input' 
I proceeded with using Pandas in Python 3

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.nativeplant.com/plants/search/input'
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[0]
print(df)
df.to_csv('my data.csv')
```

however when i am calling the read_html function it is throwing an error saying : Name "html" is not defined. 
On replacing the inside of the function with "url" I am getting an error saying : No Tables found

I don't understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: Change html to url

Comment: Yes, I did that, and the second error which I have listed (No tables found) is coming.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this pd.read_html()... Moreover, when i try a simple get request with your URL no table element are returned. I bieleve this is why simple pd.read_html doesn't work.

However,

When U click on "UpdateList" Button, this triggers a get request for data. (F12 -> Network -> Html)

You need to specify elements in params dict. Each element corresponds to dropDowns, Checkboxes in search space. Go to the browser inspector to make the connection.

```
import requests as rq
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

params = {"check":"1","flower_color":"","Ssite":"","searchstr":"","bloom_time":"","Wsite":"","H_Oper":"gt","HTSEL":"","sel_region":"","SUBMIT":"Update List","sortkey":"Scientific_Name","C_Oper":"eq","C":"","Origin":"N","show_latin":"1","show_blooms":"1","W_Oper":"eq","W":"","show_common":"1","S_Oper":"eq","S":"","show_light":"1","show_moisture":"1","show_Thumbs":"1","Thumb_size":"50","show_height":"1","show_price":"1"}
headers = {"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:76.0)  Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0"}

url = 'http://www.nativeplant.com/plants/search/report?'

resp = rq.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
soup = bs(resp.content)

## c = colnames ; d = data
c = [[th.text.strip() for th in tr.find_all("th")] for tr in soup.find_all("table")[0].find_all('tr')][0]
d = [[td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all('td')] for tr in soup.find_all("table")[0].find_all('tr')][1:] # this is the second table of the page

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=c)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code:

1. you defined the URL as variable url while in the read_html() function, you referenced it as html which was not defined.
2. The target URL is a page with frames, there is no tables in the frame. After checking its source code, the table is on this page: http://www.nativeplant.com/plants/search/default_list

The code below should give you what you want.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.nativeplant.com/plants/search/default_list'
df_list = pd.read_html(url)
df = df_list[1]
df
```

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately it throws the same error "table not found"

Comment: Please note the url I used is different.

Comment: Yes, I went to the url specified by you and executed this code.

Comment: Are you saying it's still not working? Did you notice the table is the 2nd element in the df_list df_list[1] instead of df_list[0]?